# How to solve this mathematical operation as fast as possible?

Tags: education

I am trying to overcome a test to get in a [website](https://www.openanswers.co.uk/careers/join-us). They ask me to do mathematical operations like this

> "$840 \times 883 + 991 - 109$"

and many more like this (every time) in few seconds.

I cannot do that even though I am using a calculator and copy/paste.

Is there any trick to solve it? I mean mentally in order to be approved?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell the name of that website

Comment: of course https://www.openanswers.co.uk/careers/join-us

Comment: Probably they don't want someone to join them, every time there is a new question. There is no pattern.

Comment: I agree, this is really weird, I have not been able to pass!

Comment: I have sent them a mail asking for this... :D

Comment: Great ! I am trying to apply for a position there! So let me know in case you figure out something interesting :P

Comment: Sure, I will. I am favouriting your post to remember.

Comment: See my answer. Now it will be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent them a mail asking about this, the reply was :

> Hi Jaideep,
>
> Thanks for trying the test.
>
> There are many ways to tackle this challenge. As the role we are looking to fill is for a Java developer we would expect the candidate to write a program to connect to the page, read the question and submit the answer. It's impossible to do it by hand... the timeout is very small.
>
> Many thanks

I hope you've got your answer now.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. That's not so hard, lol.

Comment: Wuao! Thank you Jaideep! I also thought in that answer, but It seemed to me very rare to read the html by java and send the answer so that I didn't try. Now It is clear and I am going to send them back the answer! thanks again. You really helped me!

Comment: @AitorMolina Welcome, and Best of Luck! I hope you succeed!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $840 \cdot 883$ means $840$ copies of $883$; if we add one more copy, then it will be $841 \cdot 883$.

That said, you have here: $840 \cdot 883 + (991 - 109) = 840 \cdot 883 + 882$.

So, by adding just one more to your expression, you would have:

$840 \cdot 883 + 882 + 1 = 840 \cdot 883 + 883 = 841 \cdot 883$.

If we add one, though, we better subtract it back off at the end.

This makes your total $841 \cdot 883 - 1$.

I doubt that more could be expected within "five seconds maximum."

Comment: I understand but I hardly think that I can solve it as fast they expected, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can cut the expression from the page, paste it into the google search bar (or maybe a window running python) and copy the answer back. All in five seconds?